# Uploading new version of theme fails, folder already exists

Tags: themes, uploads

I developed a theme for my site.

When I make changes, I simply change the version number from 1.0 to 1.2, etc. I zip the files inside a folder called `tamaltheme` and upload using the theme uploader. This message pops up:

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the theme…
>
> Destination folder already exists.
>   ...public/wp-content/themes/tamaltheme/

When I don't put them in a folder and upload them, then the theme uploads, but this time it acts as a new theme.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace your theme through WordPress I guess you first need remove the older version. That's what WordPress does when updating a theme or plugin from the theme and plugin directories.

I however would suggest to update it through FTP or SFTP (e.g. [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)). You only need to update the files you changed. It's as easy as [drag and drop](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using#Transferring_files).

Comment: I want to achieve this feature described on this page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-theme-and-plugin-upgrades/ where it says upgrade.

Comment: Oops! I did not realized that it was a plugin and not the wordpress's native behavior. It would be good to have this feature in WP built in.

Comment: :) Things that most people do not need are not included. That's what plugins are for. It has many active installs and a good rating, so I guess you could give it a try. GL with it!